# OpenLiberty throws javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException

Tags: open-liberty

I try to run a microservice (based on Eclipse Microprofile) on OpenLiberty (v20.0.0.1/wlp-1.0.36.cl200120200108-0300) on Eclipse OpenJ9 VM, version 1.8.0_242-b08 (en_US))

I run the server as the official Docker image (open-liberty:kernel)

In my service I try to connect to another rest service via HTTPS

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.target("https://myservice.foo.com/").request(....);
```

This throws the following exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: PKIX path building failed: 
        sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
        unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I already added the features 'transportSecurity-1.0' and 'ssl-1.0' into the server.xml file:

```
<featureManager>
  <feature>jaxrs-2.1</feature>
  <feature>microProfile-2.2</feature>
  <feature>transportSecurity-1.0</feature>
  <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>
```

and I also tweaked the jvm.options file like this:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=7777
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv11,TLSv12
-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv11,TLSv12
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv11,TLSv12
-Dcom.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultProtocol=TLSv11,TLSv12
```

But nothing helps to get rid of the exception.

How is the correct configuration for OpenLiberty to enable outgoing ssl connections?

Comment: can you show any additional server.xml config such as a keystore location?

Comment: I have not used any keystore location in my server.xml. I did not found how to configure that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liberty doesn't trust anything over ssl by default, so unless the service you are connecting to uses an identical keystore/truststore file, or you've otherwise configured your service to trust the microservice in some way, you can get that exception.  If this is the problem, something like this will probably be seen in messages.log as well:

com.ibm.ws.ssl.core.WSX509TrustManager                       E CWPKI0823E: SSL HANDSHAKE FAILURE:  A signer with SubjectDN [CN=localhost, OU=oidcdemo_client, O=ibm, C=us] was sent from the host [localhost:19443].  The signer might need to be added to local trust store [/Users/tester/tmp/liberty/20003wlp/wlp/usr/servers/urlcheck/resources/security/key.p12], located in SSL configuration alias [defaultSSLConfig].  The extended error message from the SSL handshake exception is: [PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target].

How to manually patch up the truststore is documented here,

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_add_trust_cert.html

but what you will probably want to do in a docker environment is modify your images to either include a common keystore/truststore, or read one from outside somewhere (such as a kubernetes secret).  By default, each docker image creates it's own unique key/truststore, and they won't be able to "talk" over ssl.

If you only need to communicate with services that have a certificate signed by a well-known authority, you can add

ENV SEC_TLS_TRUSTDEFAULTCERTS=true

to your Dockerfile (20.0003+) to enable that.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. But even I set ENV SEC_TLS_TRUSTDEFAULTCERTS=true, I got the error: CWPKI0823E: SSL HANDSHAKE FAILURE

Comment: What did you mean with "Dockerfile (20.0003+)" ?? My Docker engine is version 19.03.8

Comment: The version of Liberty contained in your docker image needs to be 20.003 or higher.  That's when trustdefaultcerts was first introduced.  It only helps for communicating with well-known certificate authorities (Google, Azure, AWS, IBM, etc.).  When communicating with another server that has a "self signed" certificate, you'll still need to patch up the truststore, or take steps to share the same key/truststore file(s) between the servers.

Comment: ok thanks, understood. I am using Let's Encrypt certificates.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Bruce in the answer above, Liberty doesn't trust any certificates by default. If you are making outgoing connections from Liberty to a server, you either need to add their certificate to the truststore you have configured OR you need to trust the JRE's cacerts if the remote endpoint is using a certificate from a well-known CA.

When you say you are using Let's Encrypt certificates, do you mean the remote end-point is using them, or your Liberty server is?

If the remote end-point is, most JRE's cacerts include Let's Encrypt in their cacerts. If the Liberty server is using a certificate signed by Let's Encrypt, that doesn't really have an effect on the outgoing connection unless you are using mutual SSL authentication.

As an FYI, if you are using a certificate signed by Let's Encrypt in Liberty as the default certificate, we will be adding built-in support for the ACME protocol in a few releases. See here for progress: https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/9017

Comment: My external service endpoint is using let's encrypt certificates. That was the surprising point, that my microsevice running in liberty could not connect to the internet because of the ssl issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as above. At present, I am working in a dev and learn environment where I want an EJB application running on a Liberty server (20.0.0.3) to invoke EJB methods and services on another Liberty server, i.e. to access methods via remote interfaces. I copied the files named key.p12 & ltpa.keys located at  ..\servers\defaultServer\resources\security from client to host, and now all working ok.

Above is a bit crude as I should probably be updating the keystores instead of sharing them. May follow up with keystore updates, but the above gets me going for now.